# Cannot invoke this function because the current host does not implement it c#

Tags: c#, powershell

i know this is on this board, but im new, and nothing has really halped me, so i am hoping someone can provide some insight. i  get the following error:

Cannot invoke this function because the current host does not implement it

here is my code

```
    public static void runPowershellScript(string scriptName)
    {
        RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();

        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration);
        runspace.Open();

        RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);
        scriptInvoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");

        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
        pipeline.Commands.Add(scriptName);
        pipeline.Invoke();

    }
```

the variable i pass through is my script name, it doesnt have a problem.

Comment: Do you mean that the server you're trying to run a PowerShell script on doesn't have PowerShell installed on it?  Or are you not allowed to set the execution policy?  It's not really clear what your problem is.

Comment: dispatching commands to the shell is not very safe anyway.  I don't know who your "current host" is but if there is little chance they will install what you need, you are going to have to approach this a different way.

Comment: Host here means the process "hosting" the powershell engine, not the server or the company that owns the server.

Answer (score 5):

You're probably using some functions which are host-specific, meaning that any process which hosts the PowerShell engine (e.g. the powershell.exe, powershell_ise.exe, your c# app) has to provide implementations for them.

In general, these would include the *-host functions (write-host, out-host, read-host), the transcript functions (start-transcript, stop-transcript), and some others.